# Qiitaへの投稿をPHPからAPIで実行すると not_found エラーになってしまう

Tags: php

Qiita にAPIを使って投稿したいのですがうまくいきません。
どなたか御教授をお願いできませんでしょうか？

```
<?php
    class QiitaApiV2 {

        public $QiitaToken ;
        public $BASE ;

        function __construct($P=FALSE){
            $this->QiitaToken = '????????????????????????????????????????' ;
            $this->BASE = 'https://qiita.com' ;
        }

        function CallApi($json){
            $url = $this->BASE . '/api/v2/items' ;

            $ch = curl_init() ;

            $headers = [
                'Authorization: Bearer '. $this->QiitaToken,
                'Content-type: application/json',
            ] ;

            curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url) ;
            curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST,'POST') ;
            curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,true) ;
            curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,json_encode($json)) ;
            curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$headers) ;
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

            $payload = curl_exec($ch) ;

            curl_close($ch) ;
            return $payload ;
        }
    }

    if($qiita = new QiitaApiV2()){
        $json = [
            'body'                  =>  '# Example',
            'coediting'             =>  false ,
            'private'               =>  false,
            'tags'                  =>  [
                                                [
                                                    'name'  =>  'PHP',
                                                    'versions'  => ['8.2.1']
                                                ]
                                            ],
            'title'                 =>  'Example title',
            'tweet'                 =>  false,
//            'organization_url_name' =>  'qiita-inc',  //エラーの原因箇所
            'slide'                 =>  false ,
            'id'                    =>  false ,
        ] ;
        echo $qiita->CallApi($json) ;
    }
```

実行結果

```
HTTP/2 404
date: Wed, 23 Aug 2023 07:51:25 GMT
content-type: application/json
server: nginx
rate-limit: 1000
rate-remaining: 992
rate-reset: 1692780154
vary: Origin
x-request-id: eb08ef99-008a-47f5-9668-517577209071
x-runtime: 0.131084
strict-transport-security: max-age=2592000

{"message":"Not found","type":"not_found"}
```

参考URL(https://qiita.com/api/v2/docs)

Answer (score 0):

organization_url_name　の例として引用されている 'qiita-inc' をそのまま指定するとエラーになります。

```
organization_url_name
記事のOrganization の url_name を表します。
Example: "qiita-inc"
Type: string, null
```

必須の項目ではないので指定をコメントアウトすればエラーがでなくなりました。